# Is there an addon for firefox that when you look at the source code xml it formats it with appropriate formatting (newlines, indentation..etc)

Tags: xml, firefox

Any help greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open it in firefox - it has a default stylesheet that will display nicely, assuming no existing stylesheet on the document.

If this isn't enough, you can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) - it will display the DOM in the html tab.

Looking around a bit also uncovered [flashbug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashbug/), which required firebug and has an XML pretty printer feature as you are looking for.

Comment: XML with an attached stylesheet won't get the automatic one, though. Neither will XHTML.

Comment: @Joey - true enough. However, with XHTML, one assumes you would want to see the web page ;)

Comment: flashbug was what I was looking for could not remember the name. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

## [Html Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/)

[image]